# 64 bit Postgres 9.1 Limitions on Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: postgresql, windows, scalability

When Deploying Postgres on Windows Server 2008 R2:

1. Are there any limitations on windows that don't exist on Linux?
2. Does the postgres scale in the same way on windows as it does on Linux?
3. Is performance on windows reasonably close to performance on Linux say within 10%?

Comment: [Posting as comment rather than answer because I don't have precise data to back it up] If you are allowed to choose the OS, I would recommend Linux because when I compare the Ubuntu and Win2008 servers we have on the same config (both types of servers running postgre9), the linux OS (ubuntu 11.10 in our case) uses less memory than win2008, so the database has more RAM available.

Answer (score 1):

1. No clue.
2. What kind of scale (up or out)? From what little that I've found on the web, it appears that Pg on Linux can handle more connections than on Windows.
3. Not if you are running anti-virus software on the Windows box ;^). There is an old (8.2 vintage) pgsql-performance thread [here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2007-01/msg00040.php) regarding performance differences. The take away seems to be "it depends" (based on usage) and that you need to do benchmarking to really know how much performance difference there will be. There is also some discussion regarding performance differences on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/222430/is-postgresql-suited-to-one-os-is-it-better-on-linux-than-windows).